# How can I return tables with different number of parameters with procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I'm going to create different temp tables depending on the @selection parameter I get, and then I want to return the table I created.

I actually wanted to do it with the function, but I got an error for variable parameter tables. The sql procedur I wrote is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report]
    (@Id BIGINT = 55,
     @selection INT)
AS
BEGIN
 IF @selection=1
 BEGIN
 Declare @tep_table table (Id int
  ,Name varchar(250)
  ,CreateTime datetime
  ,UpdateTime datetime
  ,UpdatedBy varchar(250)
  ,Deleted bit
  )
 Insert into @tep_table 
 Select * from User
 END
IF @selection=1
 BEGIN
 Declare @tep_table2 table (Id int
  ,CreateTime datetime
  ,UpdateTime datetime
  ,UpdatedBy varchar(250)
  ,Deleted bit
  )
 Insert into @tep_table2 
 Select * from Client
 END


 IF @selection=1
 BEGIN
 RETURN @tep_table
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 RETURN @tep_table2
 END
 END
```

I am getting this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@tep_table"

Comment: . . Have you tried declaring `@tep_table` *before* the `if` so it is in scope of the entire stored procedure.  Or, fix the typo in the last `insert`.

Comment: You have several issues going on here. The first issue is that you are trying to return a table variable. A stored procedure returns an int. There is no work around for that. It is intended to return the status of the execution. If you want to get data you should use a select statement. The other issue here is a performance one. You have what is known as multiple execution paths. This can cause very serious performance problems. Gail Shaw has a great article on this topic [here](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/)

Comment: `USER` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). if you *do* have an object with that name, you have to properly delimit identify it.

Comment: If you are altering a SP, make sure to remove those parenthesis wrapping the parameters. Those are used with a function, not an SP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I fixed last insert and I tried declaring tep_table before the if its not working .I am getting same error

Comment: I also notice you have ID as a parameter but it is not used in your code at all. Additionally you have two pieces of code that run if @selection = 1.

Comment: @EzLo are you suggesting that you can't use parenthesis around inbound parameters in a stored procedure? That is 100% incorrect and those are required in our shop for clarity.

Comment: What are you doing when you get the error?   Creating the procedure, or executing it?

Comment: @SeanLange Well tbh I had that idea and i checked the syntax on the docs but couldn't find the optional `(` and `)`, but I just managed to create an SP with them, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would turn this into three procedures to avoid the performance problems faced with multiple execution paths.

Something like this.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Report]
(
    @Id bigint = 55 --not sure what the point of this parameter is as it wasn't used anywhere in the sample code
    , @selection int
) AS
    set nocount on;

    IF @selection = 1
        exec GetUserData;

    IF @selection = 2
        exec GetClientData;

GO

create procedure GetUserData 
AS
    set nocount on;

    Select * --would prefer to use column names here instead of * 
    from [User];

GO

create procedure GetClientData
AS
    set nocount on;

    Select * --would prefer to use column names here instead of *
    from Client;

GO
```